# Wrangling a 2x2 DataFrame into a 4x1 Series (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to display the below data as a single pie chart in pandas/ matplotlib. What's the clever way to go about this? My method seems sloppy.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")

df = DataFrame({"Support": {"Pet Camper": 10, "Non-Pet Camper": 20},
                "Oppose": {"Pet Camper": 15, "Non-Pet Camper": 55},
               }) 
d = {}
for r in df.index:
    for c in df.columns:
        d[r + ", " + c] = df[c][r]
jd = Series(d)

pie_d = Series(d).plot(kind="pie", autopct="%1.1f%%")
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel("")
plt.title("Dedicated Pet Section?")
plt.show()
```

DataFrame:

```
                      Oppose  Support
    Non-Pet Camper      55       20
    Pet Camper          15       10
```

Series:

```
    Non-Pet Camper, Oppose     15
    Non-Pet Camper, Support    55
    Pet Camper, Oppose         10
    Pet Camper, Support        20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then convert `MultiIndex` to `index`:

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = s.index.map(','.join)
print (s)
Non-Pet Camper,Oppose     55
Non-Pet Camper,Support    20
Pet Camper,Oppose         15
Pet Camper,Support        10
dtype: int64
```

Another solution:

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = [''.join(idx) for idx in s.index]
print (s)
Non-Pet CamperOppose     55
Non-Pet CamperSupport    20
Pet CamperOppose         15
Pet CamperSupport        10
dtype: int64
```